# Receiving "Call to a member function prepare() on null" error, but data still added to database

Tags: php, pdo

I am trying to figure out what could be causing the "Call to a member function prepare() on null" in my code, but I can't figure out why it's happening. Here is my current code:

```
$password_hash = password_hash($this->password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);

    $sql = 'INSERT INTO users (name, email, password_hash)
            VALUES (:name, :email, :password_hash)';

    $db = static::getDB();
    $stmt = $db->prepare($sql); //This is the line specified in the error

    $stmt->bindValue(':name', $this->name, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':email', $this->email, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $stmt->bindValue(':password_hash', $password_hash, PDO::PARAM_STR);

    $stmt->execute();
```

The code to get the `$db` is here:

```
$dsn = 'mysql:host='.Config::DB_HOST.';dbname='.Config::DB_NAME.';charset=utf8';


        $db = new PDO($dsn, Config::DB_USER, Config::DB_PASSWORD);

        $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);

          return $db;
```

The values in this code are from a config file with all the right data in it. What confuses me the most is that this error comes up when a form entry submitted. The data from the form entry ends up in the database so I know the connection and data is correct, but this error keeps popping up, preventing my code from returning to a success screen.

Update:

Here is the full static function for `static::getDB()`:

```
abstract class Model
{


    protected static function getDB()
    {
        static $db = null;

        if ($db === null) {
            $dsn = 'mysql:host=' . Config::DB_HOST . ';dbname=' . Config::DB_NAME . ';charset=utf8';
            $db = new PDO($dsn, Config::DB_USER, Config::DB_PASSWORD);


            $db->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        }

        return $db;
    }
}
```

Comment: Did you check if the $db variable is initialized?

Comment: I haven't specifically checked for it, but I am able to add form data to my database so I assume that it is.

Comment: `$db = static::getDB();` this looks wrong. Can we see the context of the call?

Comment: Yeah, it's in a static function, I'll add the whole thing.

Comment: That's what's weird to me. You're able to add data to your database yet the error indicates $db is null.

Comment: @EduardoGalván hence my frustration with trying to figure out what's going on.

Comment: I think you also need to lookup what an `abstract class` is and how to use them!!!!! Dont just throw verbs at your code.read the manual first [RTM](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.abstract.php)

Comment: @RiggsFolly I'm must be lost. How is this an incorrect use of abstract classes? I think he is basically trying to declare a function inside of a space (Model) instead of it being in global space.

Comment: Just read the `first 2 paragraphs` in the page in the manual I linked you to.

Comment: @RiggsFolly I am working off of a tutorial for an MVC framework. The first code is inside of a user model class which extends the abstract class.

Comment: @RiggsFolly just read the first 2 paragraphs per your request. Still lost. Please explain.

Comment: @EricBrown Can you link the tutorial?

Comment: @EricBrown could you show method where  `$password_hash = password_hash($this->password, PASSWORD_DEFAULT);` is written?

Comment: @Machavity It's on Udemy, you have to pay for it, but here is the tutorial :https://www.udemy.com/php-mvc-login/learn/v4/content

Comment: @EricBrown https://ibb.co/nfCzVa   In short the problem is not in the code you provided.

Answer (score 1):

```
static::getDB()
```

I don't think you understand how that works. `static` is [used to resolve static calls](http://php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php) *from within a class*. Your main code doesn't seem to be inside a class at all. So you should reference the class name itself

```
Model::getDB()
```

Comment: If `static::getDB()` was called outside of a member method then it would have gave a different error. I thought the same thing, but just tried it. This means that he must be executing this line  `static::getDB()` from within a class.

Comment: @bassxzero If so, then we don't have enough code to answer the question

Comment: @Machavity You might want to point OP at some documentation about `abstract classes` as well

Comment: @RiggsFolly I thought about that but I didn't wanna get into it since you can actually reference a static method from an `abstract`. Could be a poor man's way to prevent insantiation

Comment: Woooow! Why the DownVote on this answer

Comment: 1. I agree that we don't have enough info to answer the question. 2. I want to upvote your answer out of spite for riggs and support for you, but I don't  see how this is the correct answer unless you know more about OP's problem that I don't.